# make selected ng-repeat list option highlight

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

can anyone help me with this problem
    I am getting an error when i am trying to make selected ng-repeat list option highlight. The item is highlighted only on second click(CSS style applied on second click) not working on the first click. And also, I have to set selected tab highlight when I refresh my page.

Here is the code:

```
$scope.idSelectedVote = null;
    $scope.setSelected = function (idSelectedVote) {
        $scope.idSelectedVote = idSelectedVote;
    };



<ul class="left-menu">
    <li ng-repeat="navigation in navigations"
        ng-click="setSelected(navigation.value.NavID)"
        ng-class="{selected: navigation.value.NavID === idSelectedVote}">
        <a href="{{navigation.value.RelativePath}}">
            <i ng-class="navigation.value.IconPath"
               class="icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            {{navigation.value.ComponentTitle }}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>



.selected {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: Can you recreate it in plnkr or jsbin?

Answer (score 0):

add CSS class like this-> 'selected'

```
<ul class="left-menu">
     <li ng-repeat="navigation in navigations" ng-click="setSelected
     (navigation.value.NavID)" ng-class="{'selected': navigation.value.NavID === 
     idSelectedVote}"><a href="{{navigation.value.RelativePath}}"><i ng-
     class="navigation.value.IconPath" class="icon" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ 
     navigation.value.ComponentTitle }}</a></li>
     </ul>
```